# How to consume java webservices from .net Client using WCF/Webservices

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, soap

I am a .Net developer using C# code. I have been given the task to call a web service written in Java by my colleague.

They gave some url (www.example.com/service?wsdl) to consume. I added that in .net project solution and created a object for service

```
javaendclient proxy=new javaendclient();
proxy.Getdata();
```

While I call that `getdata()` method I got the error:

> "An error was discovered processing the  header"

After I checked the java soap header. Like below:

```
     <soap:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" oap:mustUnderstand="1">

 <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="EK-7D1EE1EB6DD2FD216F145032375083860"> 
  <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>

  <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>  
  <ds:X509Data>
  <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
  <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=myeg-ws,C=MY</ds:X509IssuerName>
  <ds:X509SerialNumber>1424752876</ds:X509SerialNumber>
  </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
  </ds:X509Data>
  </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
  <xenc:CipherData>
  <xenc:CipherValue>
  jL+B6Zx2Gww3s6EuqN7Vgr2lddCe99HSGoxwy1kUQJvzTlSeAEj6/C4Pf97XX38NG4jOiFXUdv26pBdiIKuhx6K6CEDGIf4bvMk3eWQ85VcerMcDo
  </xenc:CipherValue>
  </xenc:CipherData>
  <xenc:ReferenceList>
  <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-74"/>
  <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-75"/>
  </xenc:ReferenceList>
  </xenc:EncryptedKey>

  <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="ED-74" 

Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
  <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
  <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-

secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" 

wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
  <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-7D1EE1EB6DD2FD216F145032375083860"/>
  </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
  <xenc:CipherData>


<xenc:CipherValue>/iWlPbyLxf9y59jRawZe4YyF3rMUPhW72bBjSHh32LlphYgCfY1Xp2YV9S4SypcLe9TkCP3KPzvoOnmTSkWUw3yCVopWx

  </xenc:CipherValue>
  </xenc:CipherData>
  </xenc:EncryptedData>
  <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-71">
  <wsu:Created>2015-12-17T03:42:30.807Z</wsu:Created>
  <wsu:Expires>2015-12-17T03:47:30.807Z</wsu:Expires>
  </wsu:Timestamp>
  </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
```

Please help me how to send the request for above java webservice from .net client using wcf or webservices...